# How to a put a repeated text in the left margin of a page, like a header or footer, but on the side

Tags: header-footer, margins, letters

I'm trying to copy a stationery format which puts the return address in a small block in the middle of the left margin of the page, like a header, but on the side  I've tried using the everypage package, and am slowly converging on a solution, but am having trouble positioning my parbox.  I was hoping somebody knew a quick and easy solution.  I am using the letter package, and using pdflatex, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Even thought it may seem trivial, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) including the `\documentclass` so that we can see what you have tried so far and help to improve upon it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package could be an option:

```
\documentclass{letter} 
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgPosition{.01\paperwidth,-.5\textheight}
\SetBgContents{\fbox{\parbox{3cm}{%
Return Address:\\
John Q. Citizen\\
500 Park Place\\
Boston, MA. 01234}}%
}

\begin{document} 

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of packages that provide absolute positioning of items on a page. For example, the [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) allows for foreground or background placement of arbitrary stuff at page shipout. The following minimal example places a similar `\fbox{\parbox{..}{...}}` to what is included in @Gonzalo's answer on the foreground of *all* pages in your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \hspace*{-0.45\paperwidth}\fbox{\parbox{3cm}{%
      Return Address:\\
      John Q. Citizen\\
      500 Park Place\\
      Boston, MA. 01234}}%
  }
}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the starred version `\...FG*{<stuff>}` only includes `<stuff>` on the foreground of the current page.

Also see the documentations of the [`textpos` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) and that of [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-pgf).