# Vertical (rotated) titles in margins

Tags: margins, titles, context, rotating

I want to write the chapter title or section subject in the margin of each page.

I eventually managed to get some working code :

```
\setuplayout[edge=3cm,margin=3cm,backspace=7cm,height=27cm]
\setuptexttexts[edge][subject][subject]
\setuptext[edge][style=\rmd\sc]
\starttext
  \rotate[rotate=270]{\subject{\rotate[rotation=90]{Some title}}}
\stoptext
```

I can play with the edge, margin and backspace width to adjust the position of the text with regard to the edge of the page and of the main text, but aren't there other/better options to fine-tune the position of the text *within* the margin or the edge ?  I tried `\setuptext[edge][after={\blank[2cm]}]` without success.

But **most of all, how can I make the title vertical in the edge/margin without having to *define* the title as rotated ?**  I.e., how do I define the rotation *inside* `\setuptext` and thus avoid the ugly double rotation (which has unwanted effect I did't try to solve when using the `\section` numbered version of `\subject` — the section number rotation is off by 90° ; it has also side effects when setting an image as the background of the title page) ?

## Desired output

The title has a page of its own (where it's printed horizontally like normal text).  On the other pages it should be written vertically on the side (like a header).  E.g. for a left page :

[image: Page example]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1446027698.png))</sub>

On the right page the title should be oriented the opposite way (the top of the title always facing the nearest page border).

## For future reference

It may be worth mentioning that `\setuptexttexts` and `\setuptext` are part of a series of commands :

- `\setuptoptexts` and `\setuptop` ;
- `\setupheadertexts` and `\setupheader` ;
- `\setuptexttexts` and `\setuptext` ;
- `\setupfootertexts` and `\setupheader` ;
- `\setupbottomtexts` and `\setupbottom`.

See section 4.16 (Headers and footers) of the [ConTeXt reference manual](http://pmrb.free.fr/contextref.pdf) (svnversion 329, September 27, 2013) for further reading.

## Update

I thought I had found the solution, `\setuphead` having a `textcommand` argument.  However the following does not seem to have any effect :

```
\def\RotateTitle#1{\rotate[rotation=90]{#1}}
\setuptext[edge][style=\rmd\sc,color=white,textcommand={\RotateTitle}]
```

(neither do `command` or `deeptextcommand` arguments).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31408/how-to-a-put-a-repeated-text-in-the-left-margin-of-a-page-like-a-header-or-foot?s=1|0.2494 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268692/fancyhdr-resets-geometry-to-adjust-header-heights/268720?s=3|0.1886#268720 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226678/how-can-i-maintain-the-current-page-nodes-for-portrait-when-temporarily-entering/227229?s=2|0.0832#227229

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not sure I understand the relationship between the two last questions you mention and mine, and the first one addresses an issue I already solved.  I believe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207393/add-some-vertical-text-on-the-margin-of-document, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256267/section-titles-in-margin-notes are more appropriate (forgot to list them in the question indeed).  Anyway both your links and mine focus on LaTeX solutions.  Or did I miss your point ?

Comment: Can you post an image that shows the desired output?

Comment: @Aditya : Let me know if the diagrams are enough or if you prefer actual pictures.

Comment: Actual pictures will be better to see how should the title align with the rest of the text. And what should happen if there is not enough space on the page to fit the title.

Comment: Do you want "marking" on the left and right of the page (similar to headers, but on the side); or do you want the section title etc to be rotated and placed on the margin (instead of in the main body of the document)

Comment: Let me know if it's better now.  I want the marking to be vertical, not the title on the title page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get markings for the margins, you need:

```
\setuptexttexts[margin][...][...][...][...]
```

For example, the following show the section title on the left margin of the left page and right margin of the right page.

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\setuptexttexts[margin][section][][][section]
\showlayout

\setuphead[subject][alternative=inmargin]

\showframe

\starttext
\section{Tufte}
\input tufte
\page
\section{Tufte}
\input tufte
\stoptext
```

Now, the rest is simply to figure out the correct rotation. I use `\framed` because it is easier to control the width of the box, but you can use `\rotate` and manual setting of the box width as well:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
\setuptexttexts[margin][\setups{left}][][][\setups{right}]

\startsetups left
  \framed[strut=no,align=high,height=\rightmarginwidth, orientation=90]{\getmarking[section]}
\stopsetups

\startsetups right
  \framed[strut=no,align=high,height=\rightmarginwidth, orientation=-90]{\getmarking[section]}
\stopsetups

\setuplayout
  [
    backspace=1in,
    cutspace=1in,
    width=middle,
    leftmargin=0.75in,
    rightmargin=0.75in,
  ]

\setuphead[subject][alternative=inmargin]

\showframe

\starttext

\section{Tufte}
\input tufte
\page
\section{Tufte}
\input tufte
\section{Tufte}
\input tufte

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

If you want more control over the location, another option is to use `\setlayer`.

Comment: I was using the edge instead of the margin because it allowed me more flexibility on the distance between the title and the text, but indeed using `\framed` is probably as good if not better in this matter.

Comment: To get the right/left correctly I add to change your suggestion to `\setuptexttexts[margin][][\setups{right}][\setups{left}][]`.  I also had to set `width=\textheight` in the `\framed`, otherwise it woud hyphenate the title.  Beside these minor points your solution(s) work great, thanks !